# How to prevent double slot invocation when showing a QMessageBox?

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots, qlineedit, qmessagebox

I've connected the editingFinished signal of a QLineEdit to a slot in my application showing a QMessageBox if the input is in some way unexpected. Strangely enough the message box is shown twice, so I put a breakpoint where it is executed and had a look at the stack trace. There QMessageBox.exec() calls QApplication::processEvents() which seems to somehow forward and process the same event again.

My stack trace the first time looks sth like this:

```
MyApp::mySlot()
QLineEdit::editingFinished()
QGuiApplicationPrivate::processMouseEvent()
QEventLoop::processEvents()
QApplication::exec()
```

and the 2nd time like this:

```
MyApp::mySlot()
QLineEdit::editingFinished()
QGuiApplicationPrivate::processWindowSystemEvent()
QEventLoop::processEvents()
QDialog::exec()
// stack trace of run #1 here
// [...]
```

I've already checked for double signal connections or different events being connected to this slot but this doesn't seem to be the problem. Can someone explain what happens here and how to prevent it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a Qt bug that editingFinished is emitted twice, you can read about it here:

https://forum.qt.io/topic/39141/qlineedit-editingfinished-signal-is-emitted-twice

There is also a workaround for it described.

```
if(lineEdit->text().toDouble()<1000) {
lineEdit->blockSignals(true);
QMessageBox::information(this, "Information", "Incorrect value");
lineEdit->blockSignals(false);
}
```

Comment: Yes, thanks. If I use returnPressed(), it's only executed once. Unfortunately the work-around with blocking and unblocking signals before and after showing the MBox doesn't work whereas it seems like for all others it did.

Comment: If workaround doesn't work for you, can you process focusOutEvent and returnPressed? Together they should be similar to editingFinished.

Comment: I finally found the problem. Multiple QLineEdits were connected to a single updateAll Slot. Then, when I stole the focus from one QLineEdit, usually pressing TAB, the cursor would jump to another QLineEdit connected to the same slot. This means, the slot checking input was running for the QLineEdit selected first, was potentially showing a QMessageBox which again stole focus from the 2nd QLineEdit currently focussed and thus leading to a 2nd slot execution. Interestingly enough it now even runs without any work-arounds at all.